# Is a question about my editing someone else on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I am both an editor and a writer. I have a question about the editing process to ask of other editors (do you use technique A or B and why). Would that be on topic for this SE? If not, is there an Editors SE?

Comment: definitely on topic per the /faq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While we currently don't have questions by editors for editors, they are absolutely on topic as long as they don't lean too much to the business side of things.  So on-topic questions would be:

- Questions about the process of editing
- Questions about working with authors or agents
- etc.

Off-topic would be:

- Career advice for editors
- Editor salary questions (although I could see some amount of gray area here)
- etc.

Answer (score 8):

> Writers - Stack Exchange is for authors, **editors**, reviewers, bloggers, copywriters, professional and aspiring writers.

Post it. If we don't like it, we'll tell you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the key word here is **process**. If you had said **editing text**, and it was grammatical in nature, it might be a question for EL&U. This looks like an area that needs development, and I would recommend not applying too many restrictions.