# Question About File Format Differences On-Topic?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I want to ask if, for my needs, it would be better to stick with Office Open XML (docx, xlsx, pptx, etc.) or if it would be safe for me to switch to the OpenDocument format (odt, ods, odp, etc.). I can include specific points about what those needs are so it needn't be purely a question of preference.

For what it's worth, I did check the [On-Topic Summary](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/875/writers-se-on-topic-summary) here on Meta, but it didn't seem to me like any of the categories given really fit my topic well enough.

Also, I chose Writers.SE over other sites because I would be using this primarily for writing; go figure.

Would this be appropriate for this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We allow questions about choosing *tools* for writing (so long as it's primarily a writing question and not a software question), so I think a question about choosing file formats would be similar.  Be sure to describe the writing-related context -- what you're writing, who (if anybody) you're collaborating with or submitting it to, etc -- how you use those files.  And you already know to steer clear of opinion surveys.

Comment: Thanks so much! :D I'll try my best!